# Find the equation of the circle which touches the $X$ axis at t

Tags: circles

Find the equation of the circle which touches the $X$ axis at the point $(4,0)$ and passes through the point $(2,2)$ .

My Attempt:

since the circle touches the $x$ axis, y- co ordinate of the centre is equal to the radius of circle. But, I don't see the centre of the circle given here. How could this be solved?

Comment: What's the general equation of a circle ?

Comment: ##Fib1123, Its $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$.

Comment: You may alternatively write $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$

Comment: First, edit your question. Some words missing. Then use the given information to determine the unknowns.

Comment: @user354073 also use the fact that the $x$ coordinate of the center is equal to the $x$ coordinate of the point where it couches the X axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to work with the equation of the circle given by

$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2=r^2$$

as this is the circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$.

You are given two facts:

1. The circle **touches** the $x$ axis at $(4,0)$.
2. The circle **passes through** the point $(2,2)$.

---

The first fact tells you that the center of the circle must have an $x$ coordinate of $4$ and that the radius of the circle is the same as the $y$-coordinate.

**Your job**: Try to put the two things into equations. Knowing that $a$ is the $x$-coordinate and $b$ the $y$-coordinate of the center, and that $r$ is the radius, what equation does the sentence "The $x$ coordinate of the center is $4$" describe? What about the sentence "The radius is the same as the $y$ coordinate"?

---

The second fact tells you that plugging in $x=2$ and $y=2$ into the circle equation will result in a true statement. This should give you the third equation (the first fact gives you two), and you will have $3$ equations for $3$ variables, $a,b$ and $r$.

Answer (score 0):

$(x-4)^2+(y-2)^2=2^2$. Just graph it and convince yourself why this should be one of the answer satisfying your requirements.

Comment: How is the centre $(4,2)$?

Comment: I have given for the case when X axis is the tangent.

Comment: I did not see that $x$-axis is the tangent line at $(4,0)$.